# Storage path not getting detected in Internal storage devices

Tags: android

When i try to run the Media player application in my mobile (Moto G), i am not able to see any .MP3 files in the list.

But when i run the same application in Eclipse emulator its is working fine and i am able to see the MP3 files in list, i have given my code below could someone please help me to solve this problem.

```
public class Playlist extends ActionBarActivity{

public final String SD_CARD = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
public List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
public ListView lv;
public ArrayAdapter<String> ad;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_list);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Updateplaylist();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Intent in2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            in2.putExtra("songindex", position);
            setResult(100, in2);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

    public void Updateplaylist() {
        File home = new File(SD_CARD);
        if(home.listFiles(new MP3capture()).length > 0){
            for(File file:home.listFiles(new MP3capture())){
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
            ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs);
            lv.setAdapter(ad);
        }

    }
    class MP3capture implements FilenameFilter{
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you added all require permissions on android manifest file ? Sometimes applications work in the simulator without adding permissions on the android manifest file

Comment: Yes i have added only one permission to read external storage android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Put a song on the root of memory and test again, I think you are checking only the root.

Comment: But in my emulator i have songs in my sdcard only, i test my app using this Emulator only it works well only in my mobile it is not working

Comment: Where is the song that you have in your emulator ? for example is in the sdcard/songs/1.mp3 or is the root destination ? sdcard/1.mp3

Comment: /storage/sdcard/song.mp3

Comment: And in your device it placed in the same destination ?

Comment: No I have not checked my device path

Comment: The path is /storage/emulated/0/song.mp3

Comment: I tested your application in my device, When I moved one of the songs from /sdcard/ADM/1.mp3 to /sdcard/1.mp3 , It appears to the list, So I think you are looking at the root destination only

Comment: Why aren't you using the MediaStore?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead it will list all song for you, I tested it on my HTC One and it listed all songs (after 13 seconds)

```
public final String SD_CARD = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
public List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
public ListView lv;
public ArrayAdapter<String> ad;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Updateplaylist();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Intent in2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            in2.putExtra("songindex", position);
            setResult(100, in2);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

    public void Updateplaylist() {
        listFiles(SD_CARD);
    }
    class MP3capture implements FilenameFilter{
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
        }
    }

    private void listFiles(String destination)
    {
        File home = new File(destination);
        if(home.listFiles().length > 0){
            for(File file:home.listFiles(new MP3capture())){
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
            for(File file:home.listFiles())
            {
                if(file.isDirectory())
                {
                    listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
            ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs);
            lv.setAdapter(ad);
        }
    }
```

You can find a better solution , It is slow on listing files.
But it show the right way to list all files.